# If stage changed to Closed Lost, then Closed Lost Reason has to be selected

Tags: validation-rule

I have to write `Validation Rule` on `Opportunity`, it has field `Stage` with picklist values and `Closed Reasons` is another field with picklist values. I need to write `Validation Rule` such that if I select `Stage` with picklist value and if i try to save the opportunity it has to throw the error, because here without selecting closed reasons i cannot save the opportunity. Also if I select the **closed reasons** value without the **stage** being closed lost it must throw me an error.

I have used the following Validation rule:

```
AND (IsClosed,
NOT(IsWon),
ISPICKVAL( Closed_Lost_Reasons__c  ,""))
```

which solves the first part of the query but I can still choose a closed reasons even if the stage is not closed lost and it does not throw me an error. Which should throw me an error saying that select a value only if **stage** is closed lost

Can anyone help in a validation rule that will satisfy both criteria?

Answer (score 3):

It will be like this:

- if Stage is `Closed Lost` and Closed Lost Reason is blank

or

- if Closed Lost Reason is given and Stage is not `Closed Lost`

then throw the validation error.

```
(ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Closed Lost') && ISBLANK(TEXT(Closed_Lost_Reasons__c)))
||
(NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Closed_Lost_Reasons__c))) && NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Closed Lost')))
```

**Approach 2**

You can make Reason for Closure as dependent picklist of `stage`.

And when Stage is selected as 'Closed Lost' then picklist values of `Closed Lost Reason` will be available and make this picklist as required in page layout.

This way, you will have better control.

Comment: It would be more clear for the users to have this on 2 serparate Validation Rules with their own error messages...

Comment: no, one is fine, Error message will be During Closed Lost, reason for closure is required.

Comment: exactly, they will be like: "umm..., I don't have stage set to 'Closed Lost'" - real life example...

Comment: Or something more abstract like "Close Lost stages must have a reason and a reason cannot be selected unless Closed Lost" That should be fun :). If you put the error next to the stage field instead of at the top it would make more sense

Comment: Approach 2 is good for this

Comment: I've implemented this VR in every sales cloud org I've ever been involved with and 6mo-12mo later, users decide they can't be bothered and want it disabled :-(